# Добавление/Удаления класса active

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net

Всем привет! Добивался 30 минут попытки удаления и добавления класса active для ссылок.
Вроде код правильный, но у меня не переходит на другие представления по нажатию на ссылки в списке...что делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### HTML

```
         <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="selectBackground">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Домашняя страница", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("О программе", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Контакт", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

### JS

```
    $("#selectBackground").click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $("#selectBackground").removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');   
    })
```

Почему эти 5 строчек не работают?
Эффект есть по нажатию, но я не могу перейти на представления:
Index, About and Contact.

Answer (score 0):

e.preventDefault() блокирует переход по ссылке.
Вы кликаете по ссылке, js срабатывает по клику, блокирует переход, выполняет действие с классами.
Можете попробывать вот это решение, немного "костыль". Но, если вы решили делать через js . . .

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var pathname = window.location.pathname.slice(1); //Получаем путь, slice(1) убирает первый символ в строке(Если нужно убрать "/")
var item = $('nav').find('a[href="'+pathname+'"]'); // находим нашу ссылку
$(item).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: теперь переход по ссылкам работает, но active класс не повешен ни на один из троих ссылок(прокликал каждую)

Comment: @Kryshtop Обьясните суть вашей задачи, чего вы хотите добиться.

Comment: @AFI19 ТС хочет сделать, чтобы линк, соответствующий текущей странице, был стилизован особым образом.